# Using 12V output as ground in 24V power supply to form +/-12V rails

Tags: power-supply, negative-voltage, virtual-ground, dual-supply, split-supply

I have a power supply which outputs both +12V and +24V, Here's a photo:

[image]

Can I use the +12V as ground in my circuit to have a -12V(from 0V)/+12V(from 24V) output?

The load on the -12V output will be ~0.2A and the load on the +12V output will be ~3A (a more powerful model of the one shown can output 4A on each output).

The "output negative electrodes" from each circuit will be tied together.

Regards,

a12

Comment: Then you will be feeding 2.8A *into* the 12V output, instead of out of it - how well does your power supply handle that? If it doesn't say it can do that, then it probably can't.

Answer (score 1):

> *Can I use the +12V as ground in my circuit to have a -12V(from
> 0V)/+12V(from 24V) output?*

You can call any node ground/0 volts that you choose. It doesn't affect its electrical properties.

> *The load on the -12V output will be ~0.2A and the load on the +12V
> output will be ~3A (a more powerful model of the one shown can output
> 4A on each output).*

Here's your picture: -

[image]

Do you think it can supply 3 amps?

Can you back-feed 2.8 amps into the 12 volt output?

Very, very, very unlikely.